Fbx not exporting

Hi,
I have a problem when trying to export to an fbx file. I had other versions of blender and it still didn't let me export to an fbx file. So I uninstalled the previous version I had and every folder related to it so I would download the newest version (4.1) fresh thinking that if I download a fresh version of blender, my problem would be solved.
After downloading v4.1, I added a simple wood material on the default cube (no bumps, no displacements, just the wood image texture). I tried to export it and it gave me this error which is the same as other times and now I don't know what to do.
If anyone knows please let me know.
Thanks.

Did you pack the materials/resources?

When the menu for the fbx settings appeared, from the drop down menu I clicked on "Copy" and then I clicked on the little think next to it that has 2 paper like icons popping out of a box.

But prior to that, under the File dropdown in the Blender interface, did you select External Data>Automatically Pack Resources?

No. Do I need to? The tutorials I've seen don't say anything about that.

That's one of the steps that is needed to export an .fbx. It will ensure that your materials stay intact once you export.

Just tried it. Didn't work

And you clicked Limit To in the export dropdown and checked the box that says Selected Objects? If not, you might try that. Then change the Path Mode dropdown from Auto to Copy and click the little icon of a box next to the Copy option.

Yeah I've done that too.

I'm afraid that is the extend of my .fbx knowledge. :) Sorry about that. Hopefully someone else will have a solution.

Well thank you anyway for all the help you could provide nonetheless.

Just thought of something. When you try to export, what happens when the error message pops up? Does it go away? Or does it just default back to the 3d space?

The error in the screenshot appears. The thing is, I tried with the factory_startup_command and it works fine. But that doesn't make sense since, as I said above, I downloaded a new version of blender with no extra add-ons enabled or pretty much with nothing extra.

Have you tried exporting a completely different file as .fbx? Or appending your cube to a new scene?

I've tried other objects in other scenes I had in previous versions but still. I think it worked a couple of times but that's it. It still doesn't make sense to me why would this still happen. Or even why is happening in the first place. I don't even know what the error says. I've opened up the code files but I don't know what they mean.

Just a wild stab in the dark. Maybe it has something to do with what folder you're saving to? Otherwise I'd say you probably want to submit a bug report to Blender: https://developer.blender.org/docs/handbook/bug_reports/making_good_bug_reports/

Well when I did this test, I exported it to my desktop. When I tried the factory_startup file it exported it just fine on the desktop. So I don't think thats the issue
